# UITextFieldDelegate method not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm following the Big Nerd Ranch iOS Programming book (Swift version) and I have this file.

```
import UIKit

class ConversionViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var celsiusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("here")
        return true
    }

    //rest of the code here
}
```

For some reason, the textField delegate method is not called. I can't see the "here" log in my console. I have double checked the naming and syntax a lot of times. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you connected the textfield's delegate outlet in IB, or set it explicitly in code?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add this part. It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need set delegate of your text field to self.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     textField.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add this part. It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Is this line present?

```
textField.delegate = self
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add this part. It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was missing a `_` in my function, after the first parenthesis:

This **doesn't** work:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
}
```

**This works**:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_textField: UITextField) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to follow these step --

1-  put `delegate` with class name .

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate
```

2- assign the `delegate` in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
textField.delegate = self
```

3- add the `delegate` method --

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    // return NO to disallow editing.
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    // became first responder
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    // return YES to allow editing to stop and to resign first responder status. NO to disallow the editing session to end
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    // may be called if forced even if shouldEndEditing returns NO (e.g. view removed from window) or endEditing:YES called
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason)
{
    // if implemented, called in place of textFieldDidEndEditing:
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    // return NO to not change text
    return true
}


func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    // called when clear button pressed. return NO to ignore (no notifications)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this function:

> func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_textField: UITextField) { }

make sure you don't mark it as private.  e.g. don't to this:

> private func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_textField: UITextField) { }

It won't get called if marked private.

Answer (score 0):

If you embed one controller into another until you add it as child to parent controller, textfield delegate methods might not work at all

Answer (score 0):

When you're sure all your code is correct, I'll add one more thing no one mentioned,
**ViewController** writes the `variable.delegate = self` in **viewDidLoad**, and **UIView** writes the `variable.delegate = self` in **layoutSubviews**.
Solving this problem wasted too much of my time.