# custom action for clear button of UITextfield in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

I have a UITextfield which has clear button enabled only while editing and it as shown in image attached.
[image]

What i need is when i tap on clear button of UITextfield it should do few custom activity along with clearing the UItextfield. As of now it only clears the UITextField only. It is not specific to clear/ dismiss keyboard.

Thanks

Comment: What activities do you want to do?

Comment: @RashwanL - after user enters data.. it will display tableview and images. So when i  tap clear button it should clear tableview and images, everything which is displayed.

Comment: Two questions: 1: Have you added a button action for the clear button? 2: You need help with how to clear your data too then?

Answer (score 9):

You can use this UITextFieldDelegate method. Don't forget to set delegate for the textfields. [image: UITextFieldDelegate]

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("text cleared")
    //do few custom activities here
    return true
  }
```

Comment: @ RajeshkumarR - i hv set delegate also.. still textFieldShouldClear does not get called

Comment: @sia is other delegate methods(`textFieldDidBeginEditing`, `shouldChangeCharactersIn` ) are called? Can you confirm?

Comment: @sia Did you copy textFieldShouldClear method from here? What is the swift version?

Comment: func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        txtAmount.text = ""
        tableViewList.isHidden = true;

        return true
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155477/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-sia).

Comment: @sia check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842153/uitextfielddelegate-method-not-called/42011726#42011726)

Comment: @sia Are you using UITextFiled or subclass of UITextField?